# when i try to setup k8s cluster on ubuntu machine I m getting error while running kubeadm init command on master

Tags: kubernetes

A.ON MASTER AND WORKER BOTH

1. Install and enable container
   i. sudo apt-get update
   ii. sudo apt-get install docker.io
2. install and enable k8s runtime
   i. sudo apt-get update
   ii. sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl
   iii. sudo curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
   iv. echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
   v. sudo apt-get update
   vi. sudo apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl
   vii. sudo apt-mark hold kubelet kubeadm kubectl

B.ON MASTER ONLY

1. (RUN AS A ROOT) Initiate API server
   i. kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address= --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qb6LF.png)

Answer (score 0):

In screenshot shared it has successfully bootstrapped master.  As non root user you can create .kube and apply the network.  It has given the join command which can be used in worker nodes to join them in k8s cluster.